# TinyMCE images with security API integration

Tags: angular, image, tinymce

In Angular project, I'm using TinyMCE ver6, and enabled the image plugin and allowing user upload images using my API, and the API need token and custom security headers, I have done the upload part using the "images_upload_handler", no issues.

the problem is after insert img tag with src url (the url is like "https://mydomain/downloadimage?id"), TinyMCE is making HTTPGET request trying to download the image and display in the editor, since my API required token and security header, and this HTTPGET request don't have that, I got 401 error.

is there any configuration that I can use to add the token and security header when TinyMCE is fetching/downloading images?